# Mobilefirst target run time error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to run a hybrid application and receive the following error:

```
target run times HTTP preview is not defined
```

Any advice?

Comment: By the way I right clicked the [project folder] -> properties -> targeted run times
And i found the HTTP preview ticked so i removed it but i can't tick the mobile first server as it is disabled.

Comment: well that would be the problem wouldn't it

Comment: i removed HTTP w left it empty with nothing ticked and it worked !

Comment: why so surprised ? didn't know about that?!

Comment: well glad i could help

Comment: i just wanted to leave a response

Comment: thanks for your concern then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't touch the project properties > Target runtimes.

I suggest for you to either:

- Start a new workspace, or
- Delete the your-workspace\MobileFirstConfigServer folder.

This should resolve the error you're facing, by restoring the project to its default settings.